Variable isn't changing (Laravel 10)
I have a view where i have a sidebar where i can select different options and change a component dinamically
My problem is that when i click the first time on one of the options it changes the value of the variable and the component changes the info, but when i do it the second time it doesn't work.
This is my blade file:
<div>
    <div class="flex">
        <div x-show="open" class="w-full text-white py-2">
            <!-- Dropdown items -->
            @foreach ($studyCircles as $studyCircle)
                <button wire:click.prevent="selectStudyCircle({{ $studyCircle->study_circle_id }})"
                        class="block px-2 py-2 hover:text-gray-300">{{ $studyCircle->study_circle_name }}</button>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>

    @if ($studyCircleId)
        <div class="w-full h-full ms-4">
            <div class="mr-5 mt-5 rounded-xl shadow-xl bg-white">
                @livewire('admin.StudyCircles.Tools.Tools', ['studyCircleId' => $studyCircleId])
            </div>
            <div class="mr-5 my-5 pb-12 rounded-xl shadow-xl bg-white">
                @livewire('admin.StudyCircles.StudyCircleInformation', ['studyCircleId' => $studyCircleId])
            </div>
            <div class="mr-5 my-5 pb-12 rounded-xl shadow-xl bg-gray-100">
                @livewire('admin.StudyCircles.AssistanceTableModule', ['studyCircleId' => $studyCircleId])
            </div>
        </div>
    @else
        <div class="w-full h-full ms-4 p-5">
            <div class="flex justify-center items-center rounded-xl shadow-xl bg-white h-screen">
                <p class="text-lg font-bold ">No hay ningún círculo de estudio seleccionado.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endif
</div>

And this is the controller
<?php

namespace App\Livewire\Admin\StudyCircles;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\StudyCircle;
use App\Models\Advisor;

class MainContent extends Component
{
    public $studyCircleId, $advisorId, $studyCircles;

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->advisorId = Advisor::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->value('advisor_id');
        $this->studyCircles = StudyCircle::where('advisor_id', $this->advisorId)->get();
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.admin.study-circles.main-content');
    }

    public function selectStudyCircle($id)
    {
        $this->studyCircleId = $id;
    }
}

Can you help me please?

The question is not entirely clear: which variable does not change? what info should be changed by the component?
If you mean that the components inside @if ($studyCircleId) should dynamically inherit the value of $studyCircleId then you need to add the #[Reactive] attribute to that variable into those compnents, for example for the Tools component:
.....

use Livewire\Attributes\Reactive; // <~~~ add this
use Livewire\Component;

class Tools extends Component
{
    #[Reactive]                     // <~~~ add this
    public $studyCircleId;
    .....


I also suggest you to add a wire:key in the foreach loop to avoid any refresh problem:
@foreach ($studyCircles as $studyCircle)

    <button wire:click.prevent="selectStudyCircle({{ $studyCircle->study_circle_id }})" 
            wire:key="study_circle_{{ $studyCircle->study_circle_id }}"
            class="block px-2 py-2 hover:text-gray-300"
    >
        {{ $studyCircle->study_circle_name }}

    </button>

@endforeach

